# Как получить текст блока?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Есть структура блока

```html
<div id="test">
  <span class="spoiler">Текст 1</span>
  Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor sit amet
</div>
```

Как мне достать текст "Lorem **ipsum** dolor sit amet" не затрагивая тег span?
Библиотека BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно удалить тег `span` перед тем как доставать текст:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root = BeautifulSoup("""
<div id="test">
  <span class="spoiler">Текст 1</span>
  Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor sit amet
</div>
""", 'html.parser')

test_el = root.select_one('#test')
test_el.span.decompose()
print(test_el.text.strip())
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root = BeautifulSoup("""
<div id="test">
  <span class="spoiler">Текст 1</span>
  Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor sit amet
</div>
""", 'html.parser')

test_el = list(root.stripped_strings)
print(' '.join(test_el[1:]))
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит, там еще есть нумерация и в некоторых строках нумерация обрезается, а некоторых остается. Получается некорректный текст